# How can i render captured frames from ndk into encoder input surface?

Tags: android, encoding, android-ndk, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview

i'm trying to capture with camera and record frames as mp4 file in android Oreo.
I implemented the capture progress using NDK.
After that, i did create preview surface(GLSurfaceview) and get input surface from encoder(Mediacodec).
However, I don't know how to render captured frames to encoder's input surface.

```
/* This is onDrawFrame of Renderer in GLSurfaceView instance 
 * The native function onDrawFrame(texMatrix) is called */
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if ( frameAvailable ) {
            Log.d("yoo", "Frame availablee...updating");
            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            surfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(texMatrix);
            frameAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    onDrawFrame(texMatrix);
}

/* This is drawing function in NDK part that is executed when onDrawFrame(texMatrix) is called */
static void drawFrame ( JNIEnv* env, jfloatArray texMatArray )
{
LOGD("DrawFrame called");
glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );
glClearColor ( 0, 0, 0, 1 );

glUseProgram ( prog );

// Configure main transformations
float mvp[] = {
    1.0f,    0,   0,    0,
       0,  1.0f,  0,    0,
       0,    0, 1.0f,   0,
       0,    0,   0,  1.0f
};

// give mvp data to shader
glUniformMatrix4fv ( mvpMatrix, 1, false, mvp );

// Prepare texture for drawing
glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

// Pass SurfaceTexture transformations to shader
float* tm = env->GetFloatArrayElements ( texMatArray, 0 );
glUniformMatrix4fv ( texMatrix, 1, false, tm );
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements ( texMatArray, tm, 0 );

// Set the SurfaceTexture sampler
glUniform1i ( texSampler, 0 );

// specify color to mix with camera frames
float c[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
glUniform4fv ( color, 1, (GLfloat*)c );

// Size of the window is used in fragment shader
// to split the window
float sz[2] = {0};
sz[0] = width/2;
sz[1] = height/2;
glUniform2fv ( size, 1, (GLfloat*)sz );

// Set up vertices/indices and draw
glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf[0] );
glBindBuffer ( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf[1] );

glEnableVertexAttribArray ( vtxPosAttrib ) ;
glVertexAttribPointer ( vtxPosAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*)0 );

glEnableVertexAttribArray ( uvsAttrib );
glVertexAttribPointer ( uvsAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*)(3 * sizeof(float) ) );

glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glDrawElements ( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );
}
```

Actualy, i tried to create the encoder instance of Mediacodec and receive the input surface of that and render the captured frames. (I refered grafika's exmaple.)
However, i don't know the way how to render captured frames after rendering captured frames into GLSurfaceView.
-EDIT-
I tried to create EGLSurface using input surface of encoder but the below error message is showed.

```
android.opengl.EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLCore.getDisplay(), mEGLCore.getConfig(), mEncoderSurface, surfaceAttribs, 0);   
/* error message */   
E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] connect: BufferQueue has been abandoned   
E/libEGL: eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect (win=0x92b7f808) failed (0xffffffed) (already connected to another API?)
E/libEGL: eglCreateWindowSurface:693 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
```

Any reply will be appreciated.